# Get values of js generated controls, from server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

Let me explain the case;

On the asp.net page, i have a repeater which generates `<tr>`s and `<td>`s.

On clientside, i have a js function which adds or deletes rows into that repeater-generated-table.

The problem is, in this function, i dont only generate a simple row, a textbox (which i have to get its value on server side) is generated too.

Is there any way to get value of client-generated controls ?

Comment: AFAIK, not in the whole txtFoo.Text way. You'll have to access them through the Request.Form collection when you submit the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who is interested in this topic, Request.Form solved my problem.

Here is the code

The pattern of the name propery is for example: `name="txtReturnCause_56"`

```
Dictionary<int, string> ReturnCauses = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
                if (key.StartsWith("txtReturnCause"))
                {
                    int _key = key.Split(char.Parse("_"))[1].ToInt();
                    string value = Request.Form[key];
                    ReturnCauses.Add(_key, value);
                }
```

Comment: Maybe i should have posted my comment as an answer. :) Glad it worked anyway.

Comment: please mention that @RPM1984 helped you find the solution. It's not nice to not acknowledge someone's help

Comment: actually, i did my best by voting up the comment which he posted under my question. wish he had answered instead of commenting though.

anyway, thanks @RPM1984 for your lead

Comment: No problems @Batu. Just glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to make the connection between the client side and the server side. You can try [THIS](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) or read [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/UsingAJAXinASP.aspx) article.

Comment: That wont help. Those links are generic "Using AJAX". He doesnt need to "retrieve" values from the server, he needs to access dynamically created HTML elements FROM the server.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would say you can write an AJAX request to send to the server the content of your textbox and act accordingly.

Beware though, that it can never interact with the server during a page generation cycle.